# How to delete a blob using Azure Functions?

Tags: c#, azure, azure-functions

I am creating an Azure function that triggers when an image is uploaded or added to a particular Azure Storage, and it does the following:
1.) Resize the image
2.) Put the image to correct directory (using Output binding)
3.) Delete the original blob image that was added to Azure Storage after processing.

I am done with steps 1 and 2 in the process, but I'm finding less to no documentation about deleting a blob or an API that would expose methods for Azure Storage. (Using C#)

Here's the sample code:

```
#r "System.Drawing"
using System;
using ImageResizer;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Drawing.Imaging;

public static void Run(Stream inputImage, string imageName, Stream resizedImage, TraceWriter log)
{
    // Log the file name and size
    log.Info($"C# Blob trigger function Processed blob\n Name:{imageName} \n Size: {inputImage.Length} Bytes");

    // Manipulate the image
    var settings = new ImageResizer.ResizeSettings
    {
        MaxWidth = 400,
        Format = "png"
    };

    ImageResizer.ImageBuilder.Current.Build(inputImage, resizedImage, settings);

    // Delete the Raw Original Image Step
}
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

To delete a blob, you need to

```
var container = blobClient.GetContainerReference(containerName);
var blockBlob = container.GetBlockBlobReference(fileName);
return blockBlob.DeleteIfExists();
```

Make sure that your close all streams before you try this so the image is no longer in use.

Comment: Nice! This is what I was actually looking for. Thanks

Comment: How are you getting blobClient?

Comment: It can be get by installing WindowsAzure.Storage nuget package. Then add the namespace Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Blob to the project.

Comment: Perfect, exactly what I was looking for, thank you!

Answer (score 12):

Be sure to have the right references imported:

```
#r "Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage"
using Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Blob;
```

Then you can use CloudBlockBlob as the parameter type and delete it:

```
public static void Run(CloudBlockBlob myBlob, string name, TraceWriter log)
{
    myBlob.DeleteIfExists();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The following function is triggered with the file upload and deletes the file afterwards.

```
[FunctionName("MyFileTrigger")]
public async Task RunAsync(
  [BlobTrigger("csv-push/{name}", Connection = "AzureWebJobsStorage")] Stream myBlob,
  [Blob("csv-push")] BlobContainerClient blobContainerClient,
  string name,
  ILogger log) {
  /// Some operations 

  if (response.IsSuccessful) {
    blobContainerClient.DeleteBlobIfExists(name);
  }
}
```

ps: Code maps the {name} with the file name you have uploaded to storage so please keep it as is.

Also documentation about it is here: https://learn.microsoft.com/bs-latn-ba/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-storage-blob-trigger?tabs=in-process%2Cextensionv5&pivots=programming-language-csharp

Answer (score 0):

You can use several input types to your function when you use C#, here's the webjobs sdk [cheat sheet](https://jhaleyfiles2016.blob.core.windows.net/public/Azure%20WebJobs%20SDK%20Cheat%20Sheet%202014.pdf) detailing most of the available ones.

In your case, you could request your input image as a [`CloudBlockBlob`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.windowsazure.storage.blob.cloudblockblob.aspx), which has a delete method. You can call this inside the resizing function or in a separately triggered function to delete the completed blobs. You may need to change your binding `direction` to `inout`, see [here](https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk-script/issues/952).

There's no binding to do automatic cleanup at present.

Comment: Tried, but gives out an error:
Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host: Error indexing method 'Functions.ImageUploadToBlobTrigger'. Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host: Can't bind BlobTrigger to type 'Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Blob.CloudBlockBlob'.

Comment: Did you change the direction to `inout`? here's a sample that may help as well: https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk-script/tree/dev/sample/BlobTrigger-CSharp

Comment: Thanks, and yes I changed the direction to inout. But still with the same error.

Comment: There seems to be an issue when using imperative binding to the Cloud types. https://github.com/Azure/Azure-Functions/issues/508

Answer (score 0):

If you're using the latest library

> Azure.Storage.Blobs

You can delete it like so...

```
BlobClient client = new BlobClient("connectionString", "container", "blobName");
client.DeleteIfExists();
```