# Cannot delete the blob that triggers an Azure Function Blob Input Binding

Tags: c#, azure, azure-storage, azure-functions, azure-blob-storage

This is a follow-up question to this question:

[How to delete a blob using Azure Functions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42129429/how-to-delete-a-blob-using-azure-functions)

When a blob triggers my Azure Function, I need to delete it once its processing is done. Otherwise, I will end up with many blobs in the container.

When I run the following code:

```
CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(connection);
var blobClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();
var container = blobClient.GetContainerReference("process");
var blockBlob = container.GetBlockBlobReference($"process/in/{name}"); // ==> This was the problem. See the answer for more info. 
bool deleted = blockBlob.DeleteIfExists();
```

the method `blockBlob.DeleteIfExists()` always returns false and it never deletes the blob.

My guess is that the blob is somehow locked by the function execution since it just triggered it.

[Update 1]

...

[Update 2]

Many thanks to @Jerry Liu, the issue had nothing to do with Azure Fundctions.

The trick is that `blockBlob.DeleteIfExists()` returns false when caller sends a wrong path by mistake.

A better approach could be using 'blockBlob.Delete' and find out what is the actual issue.

See DeleteIfExists source code for more info.

https://github.com/Azure/azure-storage-net/blob/master/Lib/ClassLibraryCommon/Blob/CloudBlob.cs#L1993

Another related question:
[Azure CloudBlockBlob.DeleteIfExists() - Does false always mean the blob doesn't exist?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48105181/azure-cloudblockblob-deleteifexists-does-false-always-mean-the-blob-doesnt)

Comment: Same code deletes blob on my side, it might be related to how your blob is processed. Could you offer some context snippet before deletion?

Comment: @JerryLiu: thank you for taking a look into this. Here is the code that reproduces the issue.

Comment: You can see my answer to that question. [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72794649/411936)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem locates at this line

```
var blockBlob = container.GetBlockBlobReference($"process/in/{name}");
```

The blob name should be `$"in/{name}"` because we call `GetBlockBlobReference` based on specific container which we have already got in `GetContainerReference`.

The duplicate causes Storage fail to find the blob. We may be confused about no related prompt/exception because `DeleteIfExists` also return false when blob doesn't exist.